# How to put a value after certain pattern in a Linux file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, scripting

I run a script which stores a value in a variable like this:

```
secret=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secretid> --region eu-west-1|grep SecretString|awk -F\" '{print $4}'`
```

Now I have a file called `env-list` which has an entry like this:

```
secret=
```

I want to redirect the output of first command to paste after `=` sign in `env-list` file, so that my `env-file` holds the secret value from first command: `secret=value`.

I am struggling a lot with this.

Comment: Did my answer solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/^secret=.*/secret=$secret/g" env-list
```